# Cypher - optimize query for impact analysis

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph, with nodes as data elements and relations representing data-flows. I am looking for a simple impact analysis query. Lets assume this graph:

```
a -> b -> c -> d -> e
b -> b
c -> b
```

Currently, my query looks like this:

```
MATCH (start)-[e*1..20]->(n2) where id(start)=70039
unwind e as b
with distinct b
with id(startNode(b)) as s, id(endNode(b)) as ee
return s, ee;
```

However this query is extremely slow and the time it takes grows exponentially with increasing the depth in `[e*1..N]` even though the result is growing very little.

For example, when I increase `N` from `11` to `12`, the execution time grows from 30 seconds to 87 seconds, even though the results count encreases just from 16k to 17k.

This tells me that it does not work as I think it does and some nodes and edges probably get traversed multiple times.

How can I optimize this query?

Details:

I am using latest neo4j and ubuntu system with 16 GB RAM and 4 cores.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `apoc.path.subgraphAll` from  APOC (Awesome Procedures on Cypher) library to control the traversal better and avoid visiting nodes multiple times.
This should improve the performance of your query as it avoids visiting nodes and edges multiple times:

```
MATCH (start)
WHERE id(start) = 70039
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(start, {
  maxLevel: 20, 
  relationshipFilter: ">", // Assuming all relationships are the same type
  uniqueness: "NODE_GLOBAL"
})
YIELD nodes, relationships
UNWIND relationships as rel
WITH DISTINCT rel
WITH id(startNode(rel)) as s, id(endNode(rel)) as ee
RETURN s, ee;
```

The `apoc.path.subgraphAll` procedure traverses the graph from the start node, up to 20 levels deep, using the outgoing relationships. The uniqueness parameter is set to `NODE_GLOBAL`, which ensures that each node is visited only once during the traversal.

You need to install the APOC library to your Neo4j instance (if you don't have it) to use the above query. You can find more information about installing and configuring APOC in the [APOC documentation](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/introduction/#installation).